# PHP/MYSQL not displaying like HTML

Tags: php, mysql

Before my images were on the database I had them stored as static so I made them come from the database. So here is my issue. While the images where static (not in the database) you were able to click on them and move through them freely, now I cant click on it and I don't know where to start?

IMAGE 1-STATIC IMAGES(HTML): http://puu.sh/cCywf/70ad438845.jpg

As you can see I am able to click on the image and it enlarges it

CODE:

```
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="main">
            <div class="ser-main">
                <h2 class="style">Gallery of honda</h2>
                <div class="ser-grid-list img_style">
                    <div class="gallery1">
                        <a href="../images/ser_pic1.jpg"><img src="../images/ser_pic1.jpg" alt=""></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="ser-grid-list img_style">
                    <div class="gallery1">
                        <a href="../images/ser_pic2.jpg"><img src="../images/ser_pic2.jpg" alt=""></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="ser-grid-list img_style">
                    <div class="gallery1">
                        <a href="../images/ser_pic3.jpg"><img src="../images/ser_pic3.jpg" alt=""></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="ser-grid-list img_style">
                    <div class="gallery1">
                        <a href="../images/ser_pic4.jpg"><img src="../images/ser_pic4.jpg" alt=""></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="clear"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Now I've made them come from the DB and it won't allow me to click on them

IMAGE: http://puu.sh/cCyzq/7d53fd37ea.jpg

CODE:

```
            <div class="wrapper">
                <div class="main">
                    <div class="ser-main">
                        <h2 class="style">Gallery of honda</h2>
                        <div class="ser-grid-list img_style">
                            <div class="gallery1">
                                                                                        <?php
 $sql = "SELECT image FROM product where productID=1";
 $result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error($connection));
 while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) //display the results
 {
 echo "<p><img src='../images/" . ($row['image']) . "'" . " " . " />"; 
 }
?>

                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="ser-grid-list img_style">
                            <div class="gallery1">
                                                                                        <?php
 $sql = "SELECT image FROM product where productID=2";
 $result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error($connection));
 while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) //display the results
 {
 echo "<p><img src='../images/" . ($row['image']) . "'" . " " . " />"; 
 }
?>

                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="ser-grid-list img_style">
                            <div class="gallery1">
                                                                                        <?php
 $sql = "SELECT image FROM product where productID=3";
 $result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error($connection));
 while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) //display the results
 {
 echo "<p><img src='../images/" . ($row['image']) . "'" . " " . " />"; 
 }
?>

                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="ser-grid-list img_style">
                            <div class="gallery1">
                                                                                        <?php
 $sql = "SELECT image FROM product where productID=4";
 $result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error($connection));
 while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) //display the results
 {
 echo "<p><img src='../images/" . ($row['image']) . "'" . " " . " />"; 
 }
?>

                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="clear"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Thanks!

Comment: In your HTML example you have image in anchor which is probably tied to an javascript, but after you use db records you wrap them in paragraph so that's why they break.

Comment: @arma Thanks for the help, but are you able to edit my code above? I'm just really stuck :s

Comment: `<a href="../images/ser_pic1.jpg"><img src="../images/ser_pic1.jpg" alt=""></a>` is not the same as `echo "<p><img src='../images/" . ($row['image']) . "'" . " " . " />";`. The first is wrapped in a `<a href>` while the second has `<p>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting this on comments request:

instead of:

```
echo "<p><img src='../images/" . ($row['image']) . "'" . " " . " />";
```

go with:

```
echo "<a href='../images/".$row['image']."'><img src='../images/".$row['image']."' /></a>";
```

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'ser' (T_STRING), expecting ',' or ';' in D:\xampp\htdocs\wd6\pages\service.php on line 110

Comment: Add ``"`` before semicolon, missed it. Edited answer

Comment: Thank you! I figured it out :)

Comment: Is it possible to also have a jQuery slider inserted in the BB?

Comment: @Sarah not really sure what you mean by BB, but you should create different thread for next problem you can't figure out :)